# Trying to disable a NetworkInterface

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm creating little tool to manage my NetworkInterfaces.
I've looked all over the web for a way to disable a nic. I've already got an instance of it.

```
    private void disableNic()
    {
        SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
        {
            if (((string)item["NetConnectionId"]) == Interface.Name)
            {
                item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
            }
        }
    }

    void Disable(string interfaceName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" disable");
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
    }
```

Neither of these functions produce the result that i want.(in fact they don't do anything). I just want to disable a NetworkInterface.

Does anyone know of a better way to do it?
many thanks!

Comment: If you don't check for errors then you can never find out why "it doesn't work".  Do not ignore the return value of InvokeMethod().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try application run with administrator permission